# Camel Rest DSL - AggregationStrategy strange behavior

Tags: apache-camel

The title is a little a canvasser, and it is of course my fault if it does not work, as it should.

I want to perform a data transfer from a rdbms to solr and mongo db.
To do that, I have to complete the following steps (for example) :

- Get customers ids to transfer
- Get custometrs details
- Get customers invoices
- Get customers payments

Then, aggregate and save to mongo db and solr for indexing.

Here is my code, but I can not get it to work :

```
from("seda:initial-data-transfer")
        .setProperty("recipientList", simple("direct:details,direct:invoices,direct:payments"))
        .setProperty("afterAggregate", simple("direct:mongodb,direct:solr"))
        .setBody(constant("{{query.initial-data-transfer.ids}}"))
        .to(jdbc)
        .process(new RowSetIdsProcessor())
        .split().tokenize(",", 1000) // ~200k ids - group by 1000 ids
        .to("direct:customers-ids");

from("direct:customers-ids")
        .recipientList(exchangeProperty("recipientList").tokenize(","))
        // ? .aggregationStrategy(new CustomerAggregationStrategy()).parallelProcessing()
        .aggregate(header("CamelCorrelationId"), new CustomerAggregationStrategy())             
        .completionPredicate(new CustomerAggregationPredicate()) // true if details + invoices + payments, etc ....
        // maybe a timeOut here ?
        .process(businessDataServiceProcessor)
        .recipientList(exchangeProperty("afterAggregate").tokenize(","));

from("direct:details")
        .setHeader("query", constant("{{query.details}}"))
        .bean(SqlTransform.class,"detailsQuery").to(jdbc)
        .process(new DetailsProcessor());

from("direct:invoices")
        .setHeader("query", constant("{{query.invoices}}"))
        .bean(SqlTransform.class,"invoicessQuery").to(jdbc)
        .process(new InvoicesProcessor());
```

I do not understand how works AggregationStrategy.
Sometimes, **I can perform 2 or 3 blocks of 1000 ids, and save to mongo DB and Solr**  but after, all exchanges are empty in the aggregationStrategy ...

I tried a lot of thinks .. but each time, the aggregation fail.

Thanks for your help

Update :

Here is a part of the CustomerAggregationStrategy :

```
public class CustomerAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {
    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
        Message newIn = newExchange.getIn();

        CustomerDataCollector collector = null;
        if (oldExchange == null) {
            int completionSize = newExchange.getProperty("completionSize", Integer.class);
            collector = new CustomerDataCollector(completionSize);
            CollectData(collector, newIn, newExchange);
            newIn.setBody(collector);
            return newExchange;
        }
        collector = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(CustomerDataCollector.class);
        CollectData(collector, newIn, newExchange);
        return oldExchange;
    }

    private void CollectData(CustomerDataCollector collector, Message message, Exchange exchange) {
        String recipientListEndpoint = (String)exchange.getProperty(Exchange.RECIPIENT_LIST_ENDPOINT);
        switch (recipientListEndpoint){
            case "direct://details" :
                collector.setDetails(message.getBody(Map.class));
                break;
            case "direct://invoices" :
                collector.setInvoices(message.getBody(Map.class));
                break;
            case "direct://payments" :
                collector.setPayments(message.getBody(Map.class));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Update :

I can log this in the CustomerAggregationStrategy :

```
String camelCorrelationId = (String)exchange.getProperty(Exchange.CORRELATION_ID);

[t-AggregateTask] .i.c.a.CustomerAggregationStrategy : CustomerAggregationStrategy.CollectData : direct://details  ID-UC-0172-50578-1484523575668-0-5
[t-AggregateTask] .i.c.a.CustomerAggregationStrategy : CustomerAggregationStrategy.CollectData : direct://invoices ID-UC-0172-50578-1484523575668-0-5
[t-AggregateTask] .i.c.a.CustomerAggregationStrategy : CustomerAggregationStrategy.CollectData : direct://payments ID-UC-0172-50578-1484523575668-0-5
```

Same values for the CamelCorrelationId as expected. 
I thing the CamelCorrelationId is correct. Doesn't it ?

Comment: How do you set the header `CamelCorrelationId`? the correlation expression must be something you can have in common between your exchanges, I think the CorrelationId is always different, then it would not work like this.

Comment: ... and if you can put the code (or at least mentioning the logic) for CustomerAggregationStrategy class it would help better what's wrong with your routes.

Comment: I don't set the CamelCorrelationID according to this: [link](http://camel.apache.org/correlation-identifier.html) _"Some EIP patterns will spin off a sub message, and in those cases, Camel will add a correlation id on the Exchange as a property with they key Exchange.CORRELATION_ID, which links back to the source Exchange. For example the Splitter, Multicast, Recipient List, and Wire Tap EIP does this."_. the RecipientList EIP do this. I updated the question with some code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, then it will never aggregate as the correlationId will be different for all your messages. 1st you have to define the "common key" on which you will aggregate and then, the strategy define how you merge two aggregated messages. E.g if you want to aggregates all message per customer, then the correlationExpression must be something like `header(customerId)`.

Comment: @ruffp Look at logs. CamelCorrelationId are same. Is it a coincidence ?

Comment: Ok found something: try with `.aggregate(property(Exchange.CORRELATION_ID), ...` because in your code you have `header´ but the correlation is a property on the Exchange

Comment: For the uniqueness or not of the CorrelationId I do not really know how it works, perhaps the id is set once per connection (like for JMS) but as you use "SEDA" I have no clue. My feeling is that it would be better to aggregate by something inherent of your messages, but finally it depends on your use case (if CorrelationId is unique per connection, you will aggregate everything as long the connection is alive).

Comment: @ruffp  .aggregate(property(Exchange.CORRELATION_ID). Tried it .. same behavior. Aggregate method is only called with direct:payments in the CollectData method.. the last route of the aggregationStrategy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it is better now.

After the tokeniszer, I set the property CustomCorrelationId like this.

```
    .split().tokenize(",", 1000)
    .setProperty("CustomCorrelationId",header("breadcrumbId"))
    .to("direct:customers-ids")
```

And aggregate on this value like this :

```
    from("direct:customers-ids")
            .recipientList(exchangeProperty("recipientList").tokenize(","))

    from("direct:details")
            .setHeader("query", constant("{{query.details}}"))
            .bean(SqlTransform.class,"detailsQuery").to(jdbc)
            .process(new DetailsProcessor())
            .to("direct:aggregate");
```

...

```
    from("direct:aggregate").routeId("aggregate")
            .log("route : ${routeId}")
            .aggregate(property("CustomCorrelationId"), new CustomAggregationStrategy())
            .completionPredicate(new CustomerAggregationPredicate())
            .process(businessDataServiceProcessor)
            .recipientList(exchangeProperty("afterAggregate").tokenize(","));
```

This work fine now and data are correctly aggregated. Thanks for your help.
You pointed out the way.